# I am trying to add another column for grade based on the score from another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, tidy

This is the code I have tried. I have tried making a function and then using that as well.

```
best <- rest_tidy %>%
  mutate(
    graded = {
      if (rest_tidy$score < 14){
        print("A")
      }  if (between(rest_tidy$score, 14, 27)){
        print("B")
      }
      if (rest_tidy$score > 27){
        print("C")
      }
    }
  )
```

However, I get this error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `graded` is of unsupported 
type NULL
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: look into `case_when()`

Answer (score 1):

```
rest_tidy <- as.data.frame(c(14,50,70,80,100,5,22))
colnames(rest_tidy) <- c("score")

rest_tidy$best <- ifelse(rest_tidy$score < 14,"A",ifelse((rest_tidy$score >= 14 & rest_tidy$score <27),"B","C"))
```

this will give you required output

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
rest_tidy=data.frame(score=c(1,15,25,35,27,NA))
 rest_tidy %>%
   mutate(
     graded=case_when(score<14~"A",
                      score<=27~"B",
                      score>27~"C",
                      T~"Other"))
  score graded
1     1      A
2    15      B
3    25      B
4    35      C
5    27      B
6    NA  Other
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's better to use something like `case_when` or `if_else` for such scenarios, just for fun, a couple of modifications to your attempt actually works.

```
rest_tidy=data.frame(score=c(1,15,25,35,27,NA))

best <- rest_tidy %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    graded = {
      if(is.na(score)) print("D")
      else if(score < 14) print("A")
          else if(between(score, 14, 27)) print("B")
            else print("C")
    }
  )
```

results in `best`:

```
  score graded
  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 A     
2    15 B     
3    25 B     
4    35 C     
5    27 B     
6    NA D
```

only the conditions for handling `na` cases and proper nesting for triggering the multiple `if` cases was required. Finally, the `rowwise` makes sure that each element is evaluated, and not just the first element of the column.

Again, this approach may work, but is not recommended.